# How to allow ZSH to autocomplete ZFS

Tags: sudo, zfs, zsh, auto-completion

### System:

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with ZFS and ZSH installed.

### Expected behaviour:

As the root user, I can press tab to autocomplete zfs commands and paths. It works both in `zsh` and `bash`. As a non-root user, I can do so in bash. It works like this:

`# zfs snapshot po`<kbd>Tab</kbd> → `# zfs snapshot pool`

### Actual behaviour in zsh:

While it always works fine in bash, the non-root user (which is in the sudo group) can not tab complete in `zsh`. I get a permission error like this:

`$ sudo zfs snapshot po`<kbd>Tab</kbd> →

```
$ sudo zfs snapshot poPermission denied the ZFS utilities must be run as root.
Permission denied the ZFS utilities must be run as root.
zfs               zfs snapshot po
```

I assume it has problems since the user do not have sufficient permissions by his own to read a particular something. Via `sudo`, the user do have permissions to do so, but I guess that the `zsh compinit` does not run via `sudo`.

But there is obviously some way to get it to work, since Bash manages it just fine.

## Q:

**How can I get `zsh` to autocomplete correctly?**